# changing the range of counts in stat_binhex

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I wanted to expand the range of counts in stat_binhex. The toy example listed on the site, http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_binhex.html, has a range for counts in the legend field, and I wanted to expand it. In other words, I wanted to make the counts range finer.

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly you mean. Maybe a minimal code example and/or a mockup graph explaining what exactly you want to change might help?!

Answer (score 3):

As for bins fill is used to change colors you can use `scale_fill_continuous()` to set `breaks=` at positions you need.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + stat_binhex() + 
         scale_fill_continuous(breaks=seq(0,6000,500))
```

[image]